# Understanding Checker Deselect

Tags: selection-tools

I don't succeed in selecting a group of faces and deselect with Checker Deselect.

Consider a cube that has been looped cut ...

Select all the faces of the top side ...

[image: Cube with a set of faces selected]

Click on Checker Deselect ...

[image]

What does it mean ?

(I am using v2.78c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have an active face. This is a way to give an indication to Blender in order to control which faces will be kept selected:

[image]

If no face is active, you obtain the message mentioned in your question.